# How to insert blank page at the begining of word 2003 document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In fact, I can insert a new blank page at the beginning of a Word 2003 document and some text.

However the problem is the new blank page will get the format or style from the next page.

For example:

The original document with bullet point:

> 1. a
> 2. b
> 3. c
> 4. d

After editing with the C# code below:

> 1. Hello world
>      
>      -----
> 2. a
> 3. b
> 4. c
> 5. d

I want to insert a new blank page without any styles or formatting.

How can I do this in C#?

Here is the existing code that I'mu sing to try and insert a blank page with some text:

```
var app = new Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

var doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\test.doc");
object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;

app.Selection.GoTo(ref gotoPage, ref gotoNext, ref gotoCount, ref gotoName);

//Insert a blank page  
app.Selection.InsertNewPage();

object start = 0;
object end = 0;

var range = doc.Range(ref start, ref end);
range.Font.Size = 10;
range.Text = "Hello\n World";

doc.Save();
doc.Close();
app.Quit();
```

Thanks very much.

I would also appreciate if you could suggest how to insert text with new line sign as "\n" doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried '\r' or '\r\n'?

Comment: @besworland Thanks for fast reply I 'll try it later but with about remove format or style from new blank page.

Comment: With regard to the line-termination request, I would highly suggest using Environment.NewLine (var s = "text" + Environment.NewLine;) as this already has the all logic to implement the correct line termination.

Comment: @embarus add a **page break** between first and second page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quit sure whether this will work for the Word 2003. I've tried this for Word 2010. The idea is to reset style of the Paragraph. Considering your code:

```
//Insert a blank 
app.Selection.InsertNewPage();
Word.Paragraph par = doc.Paragraphs[1];

par.Reset();
```

Take a look on [this](http://www.zimbio.com/Microsoft+Word/articles/0NVq6Gtp43u/C+Set+Indentation+Adding+Bullets+Word+Paragraphs) page. Hopefully this will help you.

Considering line break, I would suggest to try `'\r'` or `'\r\n'` symbols. Or as Pat has proposed, you can try *Environment.NewLine*. In Word 2010 your code works also fine, I mean with `\n`.

Comment: Hello @besworland Thanks a lot for your answer.
However there is a problem with number bullet new blank page always get bullet style.

Comment: Did you try to reset paragraph settings?

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. However thank you very for your helpful suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this problem with merge two file one for blank and one is original.

This is helpful article to solve this problem.

[How To: Merge Multiple Microsoft Word Documents in C#](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-merge-multiple-microsoft-word-documents-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the Page Break by inserting symbols "\f\r". And then set the `Style` of the first paragraph like "Normal".

For example:

```
 Range docRange = doc.Range();
 docRange.Text = docRange.Text.Insert(0, "\f\r");
 docRange.Paragraphs.First.set_Style(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
```